# FirebaseAuthPlugin.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I’ve tried over 3 days of trying to fix this error and I’ve found nothing could someone help?

/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/flutter_duelme/flutter_duelme/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 'firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h' file not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem all day long. I ended up having to bump my version of Firebase_Auth to the latest, which for me at the moment is: `^0.15.3`, which then forced me to have to upgrade Flutter as well.

Did the typical

`Delete PodFile and PodFile.lock` `Flutter Clean` `Rebuild project` `pod install`

I'm using Mac, so I also had to update my Xcode to `11.3`. Then needed to update Mac OS to `Catalina`.

Lot's of work, but this got me to a successful build. Hopefully, something in here helps others dealing with this issue.